# Should I use a comma or a semi-colon in this situation? Why?

Tags: punctuation, commas

The sentence I am considering is: "The parties hereby agree to promptly complete all filings required to be filed under applicable law[**, / ;**] such filings to be completed in substantially the form agreed to by the parties."

I think "such filings to be completed in substantially the form agreed to by the parties" is a dependent clause. Generally, I wouldn't use a semi-colon to connect an independent clause and a dependent clause, but a colleague has suggested that a semi-colon would be appropriate here.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest a semi-colon, but I would make it "are to be completed." The way it is currently worded sounds off to me.

Comment: As written (and as thereby pronounced) it needs a comma. And you should lower the tone of your voice after the comma, though that's because it's a presupposition, not because of punctuation.

Comment: NO to the semicolon. If you want to use one, change to: *such filings **are** to be completed*...

Comment: The parties hereby agree to submit all required filings promptly, following the form [format?] given below.  But "promptly" should be defined.  You probably don't want people submitting their filing one hour before the legal deadline.